# dashboard is not loading in the router-outlet

Tags: angular, routes, parent-child, dashboard

In App.routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)}]

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

in the Admin routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: AdminComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
    ]
  }
];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

In the admin component I have the  which is not loading the dashboard in it

please help me am new to angular and stuck

Answer (score 0):

Move the AdminComponent to the App Routing

```
{ path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: () => import('./admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule), component: AdminComponent}
```

And in the Admin Routing Just keep everything plain

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: DashboardComponent }
];
```

Try if this is working!

Comment: but i have several pages will load in the same place i can`t make it only for dashboard tab

Comment: Well, your code should work. Did you place <router-outlet></router-outlet> in the AdminComponent HTML?

Comment: yes i have the router-outlet in adminComponent html but it is not loading the dashboard giving blank page

Comment: Can you try enableTracing and check what is the error from the console logs? Todo that in app.routing add RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing: true})